# How to generate Events for a certain resource Kubernetes Go Operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk, kubebuilder

I'm writing a Kubernetes Operator in Go and I would like to generate events in the same way Pods do, i.e. at each point of the reconciliation I want to write an event which can be examined using `kubectl describe myresource`.

I found the package that would allow me to do that, but I don't understand how to use it: https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/record/event.go

Example skeleton code:

```golang
type MyResourceReconciler struct {
    client.Client
    Log    logr.Logger
    Scheme *runtime.Scheme
}

var logger logr.Logger

func (r *MyResourceReconciler) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        Named("MyResource-controller").
        For(&v1.MyResource{}).
        Complete(r)
}

func (r *MyResourceReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
    logger = r.Log.V(0).WithValues("MyResource", req.NamespacedName)
    logger.Info("reconcile called")

    // TODO: Record event for req.NamespacedName

    return reconcile.Result{}, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kubebuilder v1 book has a good example on how to *create* and *write* `Events` using an [EventRecorder](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/record/event.go#L88) from `client-go`.

See [Kubebuilder v1 book - Create Events and Write Events](https://book-v1.book.kubebuilder.io/beyond_basics/creating_events.html)

Comment: I didn't know about this part of the kubebuilder.io website, thank you!

Comment: Just adding a link here to something a bit more updated as the v1 is deprecated:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/issues/549#issuecomment-613506558

(an answer in GitHub for this issue of missing docs: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/issues/549 )

Hope it will save someone the 5 min of digging around